# CSS to draw slant line border

Tags: html, css

I have not much experience in web designing, I was just trying to write a css 
to get the out put similar to this
[image]

Can anyone help me to achieve this kind of header using css

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where's you code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: so many questions already asked the same.. please use google

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is an example how it can be achieved.

```css
.root {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slash {
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 5px solid gray;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="slash"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0tgwa6xn/

Comment: It's not generic at all. OP provided an example of what they're trying to achieve. Which is a skewed border. Should they have included some code, i.e. what they've attempted so far, yes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I need to draw something similar to the attached image. I am very new to css so if you can help me to write the css to get the style just like in the image

Comment: @user3423144, I've updated my answer, so you can check out one of the solution.

Comment: @hungerstar, Got my mistake. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, seem like i got what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `transform: skewX()`
It skews the object to some degree. I like using transform in css because I can manipulate the div how I like it, it take some time to get used to it and how it works but you should play around with it see if it works for you.
Here is more information on Transform: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

and I made an example  here:
https://jsfiddle.net/4r3mqctp/1/

Hopefully this helps